# Umbraco 7 : intercept user access check?

Tags: umbraco7

I was wondering : is it possible to intercept the event that checks authorization when attempting to edit a document (eg that returns error Authorization error: Unauthorized access to URL: )

and add my own checks (eg based on specific document ids, external user groupings etc)?

Answer (score 0):

In ContentService.Save() there's an option to include a user ID. I assume the saving is then done in the context of that user and that users permissions.

Also, you can hook into ContentService.Saving event and do whatever checks you want (and cancel the save if your checks "fail").

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/events/contentservice-events

Comment: Hmm, but it must be done before saving by Umrbaco itself - I went into Umbraco as myself with admin rights and edited a document. Copied the url, and then logged in again as a user who didn't have access to that document. Pasted the url into the browser, and got the Authorization error, so it must check first when you access the document. I'd like to intercept at that point, if possible.

Comment: I thought you were doing some kind of front end editing? That's why I suggested what I did. Of course you can't just override Umbracos own security - accessing a link to the backend will always require proper authentication. I thiiink there's a way to create your own provider for that authentication, but maybe that's a bit much? Here's the current UsersMembershipProvider that you would have to reimplement with your own checks and so on: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/75c2b07ad3a093b5b65b6ebd45697687c062f62a/src/Umbraco.Web/Security/Providers/UsersMembershipProvider.cs

Comment: Sorry, that link seems not to be worth much. Maybe look here for tips/current status of custom backoffice authentication: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-7032 (or here for the actual documentation: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Security/ )

Comment: No, I'm not trying oto override Umbraco's security, if anything I'm trying to make it stronger.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to override Umbraco's security,I'm trying to make it stronger. It only lets you set one root node for a back end editor as you know - it's biggest weakness IMHO: supposing we have multiple blogs - each  editable by only 1 person, but, I can't make that the root node, as they should also be able to edit news items,bulletin board items which are open to any editor.  Can members edit documents using Umbraco controls - that would make it simpler, but I don't think they can, and if I have to write my own controllers and add my own front end editing, there's no need for Umbraco!

Comment: Well, to be fair someone (not me) suggested a while ago that Umbraco might not be right for your idea. He mentioned a wiki instead, I think? I also think that some of the other stuff you're doing is somewhat of a stretch with regards to what Umbraco is and does well :-/